# How to use NameError to define a variable in Python

Tags: python, arrays, error-handling, exception, nameerror

In following Python code, I want to put variables in an array that may not have been defined. If they are not defined I would like to assign them the value of None. Is this possible?

```
try:
    array = [variable1, variable2]
except NameError:
    array[whatever] = None
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use variables that might not have been defined? Ensure that they've been defined. It's technically possible to catch a NameError, but it's usually a bad idea.

Comment: The variables that aren't defined are variable that contains past values of an RTD measurement. The past values aren't defined on the first iteration because the first measurement has no past values.

Comment: So *initialize the variables*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea, but:

```
def handle_nameerror(list_to_set, *varnames):
    for i in varnames:
        try:
            list_to_set.append(globals()[i])
        except NameError:
            list_to_set.append(None)
```

will work.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to ask why it is a bad idea though?

Comment: @DanielCDH This is not pythonic. This is a JS principle - returning undefined on name errors. Also fallbacking to None leads to confusions. In JS such confusions are not important.